# "Type Mismatch: Cannot Convert from int to ResultSet"

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I am using [JCBC API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/index.html) to connect to mySQL server in order to perform some SQL queries (create tables, delete rows, etc.).

However, I receive a "Type Mismatch: Cannot Convert from int to ResultSet" error in the following function:

```
private static void deleteUnpopularArtists(Statement statement, int min_rank) throws SQLException {

    String rank = Integer.toString(min_rank);
    ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeUpdate("DELETE FROM record_artist WHERE high_chart_pos < " + rank + ";");

}
```

I have tried to use `String.valueOf(min_rank);` and `int rank = min_rank + "";`

So my question is, why am I getting this error? What can I do to fix it?

Comment: This is what [**documentation** is for](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#executeUpdate(java.lang.String)), to tell us things like what the return value of a method is.

Comment: Consider using `PreparedStatement`, read [this](http://bobby-tables.com/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`executeUpdate`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#executeUpdate%28java.lang.String%29) returns the number of rows affected in the query. The notion of a `ResultSet` for a database write operation makes no sense

```
int rows = statement.executeUpdate
     ("DELETE FROM record_artist WHERE high_chart_pos < " + rank + ";");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
1. ExecuteUpdate returns int - for update, insert and delete operations 
where the result is expected to be int ( Number of rows affected )
```

```
2. ExecuteQuery returns resultset - useful for query statements (eg. select * from table) 
where result type is resultset (data from the table)
```

```
3. execute returns boolean - when you do not know what function to use for your 
query or for unknown dynamic sql use this function.
It returns true if result is a resultSet and false if answer is an updateCount 
or no results founds
```

Hope this helps!!!